# How to generate a Setup Project for my WindowsService which is connected to a WebService

Tags: c#, windows, service, visual-studio-2022

I'm new to Setups and I wrote a Windows Service which is working.
Now I want to use a Setup for my Customer because he is not the best with Computers.

I read the article from Microsoft under this Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-add-installers-to-your-service-application

But I can not find even the first step. So my Question would be if its even possible to build a Setup Project for a Windows Service and if how can I make it?

Thanks in advance.